# ¿Hay una forma mas simple de escribir esta condición?

Tags: python

```
 while (a==0 and b==0)or( a==1 and b==0)or(a==0 and b==1)or(a==1 and b==1)
```

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo programación con python.
Necesito que 2 números `a y b` entren a ese bucle cuando estos sean 0,0 ; 1,0 ; 0,1 ó 1,1. Me gustaría saber si hay una forma mas simplificada de escribir esa condición, ya que la que hice me parece un poco larga. De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido @Kiru203 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), favoreciendo así tus chances de obtener una buena recepción por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: La respuesta corta es `while True:` (no olvidar `:` al final) dado que estás poniendo todas las combinaciones `2^2 = 4` `(0,0 ; 1,0 ; 0,1 ó 1,1)`esto implicaría que nunca pararía el bucle `while` a menos claro que haya un `break` dentro del citado bucle.

Comment: @HubertRonald tu propuesta de `True` sería sólo en el caso de que a y b tuvieran como valores 0 y 1 únicamente, pero podrían tomar cualquier otro número como 5 o 6. Pero si sólo es el rango [0, 1] favorezco tu comentario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que una forma de simplificarlo seria con un *chequeo de membresía* o *verificación de membresía*, lo cual es comparar si un valor se encuentra en una lista.

```py
i=0
a=0 #lo cambias a 1
b=0 #lo cambias a 1
while a in [0,1] and b in [0,1]:
    print("yess")
    i+=1
    if i == 10: break
```

Y de esta forma si quieres validar mas valores solo lo pones en la lista.

Comment: También puedes usar `while (a, b) in [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]:`, que es más "extensible": sólo hay que agregar tuplas a la lista.

Answer (score 2):

Analicemos el caso general: tenemos un conjunto de variables `a, b, c, ...` y queremos chequear que `a==x and b==y ...` para alguna tupla `(x, y, ...)` dentro de una lista de valores aceptables.

En Python, la expresión `bar in foo` retorna `True` si `bar` es un elemento de `foo`, sin importar que los tipos específicos involucrados, por lo que es válido preguntar si una tupla de valores está en una lista de tuplas, con lo que problema del OP se resuelve así:

```
aceptables = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]

while True:
    a=int(input("a? "))
    b=int(input("b? "))
    if (a, b) in aceptables:
        print(f"({a}, {b}) es aceptable.")
    else:
        print(f"({a}, {b}) es rechazado.")
```

#### Ventajas

La primera ventaja es versatilidad. Puedo agrandar o acortar la lista de valores permitidos sin tener que cambiar el código. Por ejemplo, si queremos descartar la condición `a==0 y b==0`, basta con sacarla de la lista:

```
aceptables = [(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]
```

La segunda ventaja es la extensibilidad. En el ejemplo operamos con dos variables, pero el código funciona lo mismo con diez o cien; es cosa de agrandar la lista de `aceptables`.

Finalmente, la solución es paramétrica. Podemos escribir está función general:

```
def revisa_igual(valor, aceptables):
    return valor in aceptables
```

y usarla

```
valores = (0, 1)
if revisa_igual(valores, aceptables):
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Bad")
```

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que la condición evaluar pareciera tratarse de un producto cartesiano, si efectivamente este fuera el caso, puede ser útil generarlo dinámicamente:

```
import itertools

combinaciones = list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=2))
print(combinaciones)

[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Por lo que finalmente la clausula quedaría así:

```
while (a, b) in combinaciones:
    pass
```

El beneficio obvio de esto, es si el día de mañana las variable crecen en condiciones o en número de variables es fácil redefinir la lista de combinaciones a evaluar

Comment: Aún más fácil sin necesidad de `itertools` ni conversiones:  `combinaciones = [(i,j) for i in (0,1) for j in (0,1)]`